# How is my model and data dictionary instance incorrect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a web application with .net core 2.2 mvc. I am having an issue with bringing back data to my partial view. It seems when I pass data from my sql server stored procedure I am getting this error : An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[DineEquip.Models.ReportSingle]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'DineEquip.Models.ReportSingle'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)

I have rewritten the model, controller and view and even started a new project to see if that was the issue but still get the same error. I see that this type of error is posted here but none of the answers seemed to have helped me solve this issue, since I am just bring back one record. I am hopeful that someone out there can point out just what I am doing wrong.

------------------model------------------------

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DineEquip.Models
{
    public class ReportSingle
    {
        [Key]
        public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Serial Number")]
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fixed Asset Number")]
        public string FixedAssetNo { get; set; }


    }
}
```

--------context---------

```
namespace DineEquip.Data
{
    public class DineEquipContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Models.ReportSingle> ReportSerial { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

-------controller-------

```
public IActionResult ReportSerial(string Serial)
        {

            var sqlSerial = new SqlParameter("@SearchSerialNo", Serial);

            return PartialView(_context.ReportSerial.FromSql("exec DiningEquipmentReportSerial @SearchSerialNo", sqlSerial));

        }
```

---View- main---------

```
@model  ReportSingle
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SearchDetails";
}



<form asp-controller="DineEquip" asp-action="ReportSerial" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Serial Number to find :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="Serial" asp-for="SerialNo" name="Serial" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

------View-partial------

```
@model ReportSingle

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SerialNo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FixedAssetNo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Make)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SerialNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FixedAssetNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Make)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Model)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Location)
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The partial view should return the results from the Stored procedure. Any help/direction on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Results from a DB generally are in memory queries hence IQueryable and are not executed until they are referenced. The result coming back from `_context.ReportSerial.FromSql(...)` is in memory and hasn't technically been executed to get the results yet. Try a .FirstOrDefault() off the end of .FromSql. This should execute the query and return the first result.

Comment: Awesome that was it! Thank you so much for the insight and the prompt response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue. @Bret Lipscomb was completely correct. To solve the issue all I had to do was to add .FirstOrDefault() after my context statement like so : `return PartialView("ReportSerial", _context.ReportSerial.FromSql("exec DiningEquipmentReportSerial @SearchSerialNo", sqlSerial).FirstOrDefault());`